# ee.Algorithms.If result gives "not a function" error on relational method call (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, masking

I am trying to filter an image collection by Quality Control bands. The quality control bands are named two different things (`"QA"` and `"qaGpp"`), and these names do not appear to within the collection with any inherent order, so slicing the Image Collection will not work.

Thus, I need to specify the correct band to be selected during mapping as follows:

```
//Load in Image Collection:
var TPP = ee.ImageCollection("UMT/NTSG/v2/LANDSAT/GPP")


var QC = function(image){
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  var hasQC = ee.Filter.eq(bandNames.get(1), 'QC');
  var ifElse = ee.Algorithms.If(hasQC,image.select("QC"),image.select("qaGpp"));
  return image.updateMask(ifElse.neq(255));
};

//Map QC mask to image collection:
var TPPMasked = TPP.map(QC);

//Yields the following error: ifElse.neq is not a function
```

An examination of a single Image within the collection reveals that `ifElse` is indeed an Image, which should be able to take a `.neq` method:

```
//Take arbitrary Image from collection and run the previously mapped function on it:
var testTPP = TPP.first();
var bandNames = testTPP.bandNames();
var hasQC = ee.Filter.eq(bandNames.get(1), 'QC');
var ifElse = ee.Algorithms.If(hasQC,testTPP.select("QC"),testTPP.select("qaGpp"));
print(ifElse, "ifElse");



//Here is the error:
print(ifElse.neq(255));
```

How do I correctly mask these Images such that all image with their respective QC bands that don't have a value of 255 are thrown out?

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1b31d08453d787d372bf1f4bc4ff7ff) is a link to the code in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ifElse.neq is not a function` error is because the object returned from `ee.Algorithms.If()` does not have an explicit type and therefore does not have a `.neq` method available to it as interpreted in the evaluation of the execution graph for your request. You need to cast the result as an `ee.Image`:

```js
var ifElse = ee.Image(
       ee.Algorithms.If(hasQC,testTPP.select("QC"),testTPP.select("qaGpp")))
```

If the second band is always expected to be the quality band, why not just ensure that all band names for the second band are "QC" to avoid having to do `ee.Algorithms.If`:

```js
var gppQc = TPP.map(function(img) {
  return img.rename(['GPP', 'QC']);
});
```

This will make the second band for all images "QC".